# How can i show datas with setonItemListener in another activity

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have an app.i work with sqlite offline database. 
i have 1 image and 3 text in my database.i think i can load datas in gridview . i don't have any problem with that. 
and i have 50 icon and topics.i want that when user clicks on Item 
 (setonitemListener) my app move to another activity and show only that topic in the second activity
 i have two-way to create this app 
1- create 50 activity and do setonClickListener (it's not proffesional) 
2- SetOnItemListener and move datas to second activity.

So. I'm Saving Image Names on db and saving images in assest folder 
So When app starts and user clicks on one item. it'll intent to another activity and it should load That Field in db in my app(Texts and Image)i think i should get POS, right? how should i do that? HEEELPPP!!!!!

my problem is

```
List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { @Override public
void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) { // 
TODO Auto-generated method stub // // HOW SHOULD I TRANSER DATAS TO ANOTHER 
ACTIVITY AND LOAD IT . in this activity i just have 50 icons or text that 
loads from database. my question is how can i show them in another activity 
with full contents from db . 
}
```

Comment: Show your code first! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i'm just loading my contents in a listview or gridview. 
my problem is 
        List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //                
                    // HOW SHOULD I TRANSER DATAS TO ANOTHER ACTIVITY AND LOAD IT . in this activity i just have 50 icons or text that loads from database. my question is how can i show them in another activity with full contents from db . 
}

Answer (score 0):

Get all the information you need from the grid, use **setOnItemClickListener** and access whats you want(and also get the Id to access the row from DB). Now move this data to next activity by intent. In your next activity run a query to get data from a particular row with the help of Id, and then you will have all the things you needed.

Comment: i should transfer it with  .putExtra , right? so how should i get id and show it in my second activity?

Comment: As you are getting other data from the columns of SQLite db.

Comment: can i have your email address? :/
ixeeu7@gmail.com